# Rank aggregation on an uneven dataframe

Tags: r

I am attempting to perform a rank aggregation with the RankAggreg package on a dataset that is uneven, and has NA's filling the rest of the data frame.

I am getting the error:

```
library(RankAggreg)
top25CE <- RankAggreg(Ranks3, 5, seed=100, rho=.01)

"Error in RankAggreg(Ranks3, 5, seed = 100, rho = 0.01) : 
  Elements of Each Row Must Be Unique"
```

that I believe is from the NA's filling the bottom of the dataframe. The dataframe is 53 columns wide and 11 rows long, with the end of all but 1 column being NA's, similar to the example table here:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 |
| NA | 5 |
| NA | NA |

I was wondering if this can work within the RankAggreg package or another ranking package type, or if using uneven dataframes doesn't work for this type of analysis?
Thank you!

edit: [image of a part of the dataset used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpoMl.png)

Comment: please clarify Ranks3 and its contents; its expected this would be a matrix not a dataframe

Comment: I added an image of part of the dataset to the post, and it does come back as true when testing if it is a dataframe, but not sure if that is enough.

Comment: images arent really useful for the most part, as I wont be typing it out; but I suppose it told me one thing. that your data is probably organised incorrectly. each list should form a row, not a column. but I cant get over how you arent simply getting an error due to not using a matrix, so its confusing on that point

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example will make it a lot easier for responses to be able to find a solution for you, without having to type out a copy of your data from the image you posted (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Reading the documentation for the package is also a useful first step (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RankAggreg/RankAggreg.pdf)

It looks as though RankAggreg() is expecting your data to be in a different form. Rather than having each location be a column and listing species downwards in each row, transform your dataset such that each location is a row, and the species are listed across columns in order (i.e. columns would be the position number of a particular species in an ordered list).

Edit: After experimenting with the example given in the documentation, the error message is telling you the problem: The elements of each row (in your case, list of species) must be unique. That is, none can repeat - not even NA. I retried this using NULL instead and found the same error.

I'm not experienced in rank aggregation, so I do not think I see any valid solutions unless there are alternative packages which can handle this kind of data. I suspect my initial ideas (take only the top n entries from each location, where n is the length of your shortest list OR replace 'NA' with unique dummy entries 'NA1', 'NA2', 'NA3'...) are likely to introduce other problems in your results.

My suggestion if no better package/function can be found: read around other research/studies or contact others in the area to see how this issue is typically resolved, as I believe the problem is not in your code, but your data

Comment: Okay, will do in the future my bad! After making my example in the way that it is shown in the form of the documentation example and how you explained (row names being location and filled with the species for each of those) the result is now a matrix (as expected by Nir Graham, but I am receiving the exact same error. Let me know if any more info would be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Edited my answer, I think the issue is in your data, not in your code. Hopefully the code should work as expected once you've found the conventional way to resolve the data.

Comment: Thanks KSkoczek! I'll definitely look into it and post a response/work around if I find one (unless anyone else has anything)

Answer (score 0):

You probably simply need to transpose your data with `t()`

```
library(RankAggreg)

(mydata <- data.frame(choices_of_person_1=1:5,
                     choices_of_person_2=c(1:3,rep(NA,2)),
                     choices_of_person_3=c(4:3,rep(NA,3))))

(people_are_rows <- t(mydata))

# FAILS 
(res <- RankAggreg(mydata, k=2,rho = 1))
# Error in RankAggreg(mydata, k = 2, rho = 1) : 
#   Elements of Each Row Must Be Unique

# Gives an output
(res <- RankAggreg(people_are_rows, k=2,rho = 1))
```

Comment: I did transpose in order to receive an answer, but that is due to the low k value only providing 2 results. I wanted a higher k value to be produced, just ignoring the NAs, rather than including them in the analysis. Such as the same example you gave, only with k=5 representing all columns, rather than the first 2. Thanks so much!